Grouping objects by a set of criteria
I want to solve a particular need I have, so I will demonstrate the idea using a simple example:
Datatypes:
data Activity = Activity
  { activityName :: String
  , purpose :: Purpose
  , timeOfDay :: TimeOfDay
  , location :: Location
  }
  deriving (Show, Eq)

data Purpose = Work | Personal | Leisure
  deriving (Show, Eq)

data TimeOfDay = Morning | Afternoon | Evening
  deriving (Show, Eq)

data Location = Home | Office | Elsewhere
  deriving (Show, Eq)

Example:
activities =
  [ Activity "Check emails" Work Morning Office
  , Activity "Attend project meeting" Work Afternoon Office
  , Activity "Go for a run" Leisure Afternoon Elsewhere
  , Activity "Prepare dinner" Personal Evening Home
  , Activity "Watch a movie" Leisure Evening Home
  , Activity "Read a book" Leisure Evening Home
  ]

Predicates:
isWorkRelated :: Activity -> Bool
isWorkRelated activity = purpose activity == Work

isAfternoonActivity :: Activity -> Bool
isAfternoonActivity activity = timeOfDay activity == Afternoon

isAtHome :: Activity -> Bool
isAtHome activity = location activity == Home

Problem:
I would like to group activities according to the predicate(s) they satisfy. Are there any standard Haskell pattern I can use to solve it ? The solution should enable convenient access to an arbitrary group that satisfies a predicate (I would then need to process each of them in a different way, of course).
I would appreciate any insights into this.
P.D: This is one of my attempts:
groupByCriteria :: [a -> Bool] -> [a] -> [(a -> Bool, [a])]
groupByCriteria ps acts = [(p, filter p acts) | p <- ps]

However, I would prefer to have a String label to indicate which predicate is satisfied instead of a function (a -> Bool).

Perhaps make a data type with both a name and a predicate?

You can just change the data type with:
data Group a = Group String (a -> Bool)

isWorkRelated :: Group Activity
isWorkRelated = Group "work-related" (\activity -> purpose activity == Work)

isAfternoonActivity :: Group Activity
isAfternoonActivity = Group "afternoon" (\activity -> timeOfDay activity == Afternoon)

isAtHome :: Group Activity
isAtHome = Group "at-home" (\activity -> location activity == Home)
and then group with:
groupByCriteria :: [Group a] -> [a] -> [(String, [a])]
groupByCriteria ps acts = [(name, filter p acts) | Group name p <- ps]


Thank you so much ! I am wondering what happens with an activity that satisfies both predicate 1 and 2, like: Activity {activityName = "Attend project meeting", purpose = Work, timeOfDay = Afternoon, location = Office}]). Do you have any thoughts ? I see the order of the predicates matter.

Ideally, for the general solution, I would have to prove that the solutions satisfied by each of the predicates do not have elements in common, I think ? Those sets would yield a disjoint union. Not sure if that is solvable.

Or, give a list of all the predicates which satisfy each activity

@F.Zer If you want a guarantee that predicates don't overlap, predicates are the wrong tool. You need an enum type listing the categories, and a classification function placing each item in a category.

Thank you @amalloy, that sounds great ! Wouldn't the classification function be a predicate ?

@F.Zer A predicate returns true or false.

@amalloy Sure, yes. I expressed in an incorrect way. Wouldn't the classification function contain a predicate ? If so, how can I be sure those conditions don't overlap ?

@F.Zer Perhaps you should ask a separate Question about grouping the activities into disjoint sets.

Good, @amalloy. That makes sense.
